# CSF Filter for creating Bare Earth Model use in Agisoft

Tags: photogrammetry

Can anybody tell, how to use CSF filter Plugin(Cloud Compare) in Agisoft. I am having Agisoft Metashape Professional

Comment: Have you seen this link from the Agisoft Forums about using CSF and the related parameters?  https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=7976.0

Comment: Yes. I seen that but I can't download cloud compare due to it restrictions in company. That's why I asked how to add CSF DLL or python script available on GitHub in agisoft..